# There is no API in JS add-ins for Office 365 to work with notes

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

In Excel 365 online, notes are now displayed as comments, but there is no access to notes from the JS add-in. Excel API does not allow to work with them.

Are there any plans to extend Excel 365 API for JS add-ins for work with notes?

Comment: Hi there, we currently did not have plans to add support for Excel notes API. Modern comments are meant to be used in place, and have more capabilities like the ability to assign and @mention other participants allowing for better co-authoring.

Is your question indicating a bug that the notes themselves while they appear as comments aren't accessible at all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
In Excel Online, notes are not recognized by using Excel JS API, even though they are displayed as comments. We used context.workbook.comments. This is probably a bug.
If we try to add @mention, Excel Online offers a convert note to a threaded comment. Can we convert notes or interact with them using Excel JS API?